# What is the best way to refer to the force that acts upon the needle of a compass?

Tags: electromagnetism

I just called it Lorentz force, but the Lorentz force actually implies an electric field and moving particles. So what is the best name for the force that makes the needle move? Magnetic force? And can I also still call it Lorentz force since the magnetic force is also described by Lorentz Force's law?

Comment: All electromagnetic forces are, eventually, Lorentz forces.  It's probably simpler to just call the force on a compass "Magnetism", though.

Comment: Maybe a magnetostatic force?